# empty when document exist in local mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect mongodb and express using mongoose ORM.But returns empty even if the document exist.I have a moviedb set up already it has this document.what am i missing here?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db27279eb5046242c59d466"), "moviename" : "The Godfather", "Genre" : "Drama/Crime", "Rating" : "9.2/10" }


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/moviedb', {useNewUrlParser: true});
let db = mongoose.connection;


db.once('open',function(){
    console.log('connected to db');  
})
db.on('error',function(err){
    console.log(err);

})
app.get('/movies',function(req,res){
    Movie.find({},function(err,movies){
        if(err){
            console.log('err');

        } else{
            console.log("from the /movies",movies);

            res.render('movies',{
                title:'Movies',
                movies:movies
            })
        }
    }) 
})
```

Comment: May be an obvious question, but are you creating a mongoose.Schema and mongoose.model() for Movie?

Comment: Does  console.log("from the /movies",movies);  outputs something? Also can you add your Movie model code to the question?

Comment: Would be nice if you shared you movies schema and model